# Issue with disabling transition animation if checked with Tumblr meta tags

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr, meta-tags

I am simply trying to give the theme user an option on
having the animation or not, so I used this

`<meta name="if:Transition" content="1"/>`

with this `{block:iftransition}` around the css.

**full example//**

```
{block:iftransition}
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
{/block:iftransition}
```

but when I turn the switch on or off nothing happens to the animation at all.
It only works for showing the description....

As an example//

[This](http://pastebin.com/bTE4czGb#) theme
you get the option to turn box-shadow on or off.

They used this meta tag//

`<meta name="if:Box shadow" content="1"/>`

and this css//

```
{block:ifboxshadow}
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
{/block:ifboxshadow}
```

and it works perfectly.

So I tried to create a transition meta tag and failed.
My question is:
Why doesn't my code work?
But yet another theme's code does?
What am I doing wrong?
Please help.

Comment: It's a bit of a stab in the dark but is your {block:iftransition} wrapped inside some other css? I think that might be required.

Comment: To follow on what @lharby said, what are the transition properties being applied to?